# How do I put "calculating abilities" into TKinter entrys?

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

So I more or less scrapped my old diabetes calculator to make this new one with a GUI. But now my lack of knowledge strikes again...

Could anyone help me how to create a calculator with TKinter entries?

New code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.wm_title("DiabetesC")

label_1 =Label(root, text='Kolhydrater')
label_2 =Label(root, text='Insulin igår?')
label_3 =Label(root, text='Regel, 330/500?')

label_version =Label(root, text='DiabetesC v.0.0.1 made by Pantburken')

entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_2 = Entry(root)
entry_3 = Entry(root)

button_1 = Button(root, text='Räkna ut!')

label_version.grid(row=0, column=1)

label_1.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
label_2.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
label_3.grid(row=3, sticky=E)

entry_1.grid(row=1, column=1)
entry_2.grid(row=2, column=1)
entry_3.grid(row=3, column=1)

button_1.grid(row=4, sticky=E)
root.mainloop()
```

Old code:

```
kolhydrater = int(input('Hur många gram kolhydrater är det i livsmedlet? ')
insulin = int(input('Hur många enheter insulin tog du igår? ')
regeln = int(input('300/500/100 regeln? ')
noname = int(regeln / insulin)
enheter = int(kolhydrater / noname)
print (enheter)
```

So the main idea is to put the functionality of the old code into the new code with GUI if you understand what I mean?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... are you looking for button callbacks?

Comment: Ehm what's that? What I'm asking is how I make it so if you type numbers in the three boxes, Python will automatically execute an equation. Do you understand? :)

Comment: Google Translate says that "Räkna ut!" is Swedish for "calculate," so it looks like you have a button to perform the calculation. Do you want the user to click the button, or do you want the calculation to happen automatically as soon as the user enters a number? If you want them to use a button, you need a [callback](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.html). If you want it to happen automatically, you also need to [trace variables](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).

Comment: I wan't it to happen when the button is pressed, I'll read those texts and try  using it tomorrow since its past midnight in Sweden! Thanks :D

Comment: Du är välkommen, god natt.

Comment: Haha, that translation went bad, You're welcome would actually translate into "Varsågod". Google translate doesn't do a good job translating sentences into words :P

Comment: It gave me "Varsågod" for just "you're welcome," but then changed it when I added "good night." =\ Anyway, give it a try tomorrow; it's pretty quick once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your will, and i just wanted to tell you that you should try to give your variables more meaningful names. For now i didn't changed them, just noting.

This is what you should do, the button need to have a command that calls a function that calculate the formula and then show at the gui.

```
from tkinter import *

def calc_result():
    noname = int(entry_3.get()) / int(entry_2.get())
    enheter = int(entry_1.get()) / int(entry_2.get())
    label_4 =Label(root, text='Result, ' + str(enheter))
    label_4.grid(row=5, sticky=SE)

root = Tk()

root.wm_title("DiabetesC")

label_1 =Label(root, text='Kolhydrater')
label_2 =Label(root, text='Insulin igår?')
label_3 =Label(root, text='Regel, 330/500?')

label_version =Label(root, text='DiabetesC v.0.0.1 made by Pantburken')

entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_2 = Entry(root)
entry_3 = Entry(root)

button_1 = Button(root, text='Räkna ut!', command=calc_result)

label_version.grid(row=0, column=1)

label_1.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
label_2.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
label_3.grid(row=3, sticky=E)

entry_1.grid(row=1, column=1)
entry_2.grid(row=2, column=1)
entry_3.grid(row=3, column=1)

button_1.grid(row=4, sticky=E)
root.mainloop()
```

**NOTE:**

It will be much easier to handle and manage everything within a class.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, but I don't think your question is correct: you don't need the auxiliary verb `do` in this case, because you have the `be` verb, so your question should be: `Was my answer helpful?`

Comment: Well.. Was my answer helpful? @Pantburken

Comment: I think so, but now it tells me this: AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'get'. Oh and I typed the equation wrong... It should've been something like in the old code (edited it) @omri_saadon

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get the data with entry.get() as you can't do math in the tkinter entries.
First get all the values then do the math..

Comment: Can you explain more detailed? Didn't quite understand :/